# using controllers from multiple modules in scope section

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to build an Oauth2 server (called Oauth2srv) using shield. But that is not what the question is about. The example code basically says to do this:

```
scope "/", Shield do
  pipe_through :api

  get "/apps", AppController, :index
  .. etcetera ..
end
```

The Shield module is in a dependency, so resides in deps/shield. All the routes are there too.
Now I want to add a route to a controller in my own module like this:

```
scope "/", Shield do
  pipe_through :api

  get "/apps", AppController, :index
  get "/*", Oauth2srv.CatchallController, :catch_it
end
```

The CatchallController resides in web/controllers/catchall_controller.ex. But the scope seems to expect all controllers in the same directory, and the compiler throws me an error: `function Shield.Oauth2srv.CatchallController.init/1 is undefined`.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Just a note on you saying "the scope seems to expect all controllers in the same directory". That is not how Elixir works. Elixir is a compiled language. So you could technically put a module in any directory, despite the name. Though, it is usually useful to have the directory structure follow the module name for convenience on finding modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you will want to use a different scope. When you did

```
scope "/", Shield do
  get "/apps", AppController, :index
end
```

You are saying that you have a module named `Shield.AppController`, so when you added the catch all route inside the `Shield` scope, you are telling the compiler that you have a `Shield.CatchallController` module.

Though, according to your error, the compiler is looking for a `Shield.Oauth2srv.CatchallController` (note the `Oauth2srv`). So you either didn't give all of the information, or there is something else happening.

If these are the only 2 routes that you are defining in your application, you can do something like

```
scope "/" do
  get "/apps", Shield.AppController, :index
  get "/*", MyApp.CatchallController, :catch_it
end
```

If you have more, you may want to specify multiple scopes. Something like

```
scope "/", Shield do
  get "/apps", AppController, :index
  get "/something_else, OtherController, :foo
  ...
end

scope "/", MyApp do
  get "/*", CatchallController, :catch_it

  # Other routes that are important to your application
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Turns out I don't really understand what the scope verb does. Is it a function? Never touched Ruby, so still having trouble recognizing the functions-without-parenthesis.

Comment: So do I understand correctly that the scope is a function taking a path prefix, a scope name which tells it to prefix that scope to all Controller names, and a function that adds routes to a global list of routes?

Comment: [`scope`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Router.html#scope/2) is a macro. You also mention not touching Ruby, Elixir is very different from Ruby. You would do yourself and others a disservice by trying to directly compare the two.

Comment: I wasn't comparing, my comment was centered around  encountering functions that have no parenthesis in Elixir, which was the first time I ever saw that, and it happens to confuse me every time. Googling around led me to believe that this was first widely practiced in Ruby, and the guy who designed Elixir was a long-time Ruby developer.